# How to invert the x or y axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a scatter plot graph with a bunch of random x, y coordinates. Currently the Y-Axis starts at 0 and goes up to the max value. I would like the Y-Axis to start at the max value and go up to 0.

```
points = [(10,5), (5,11), (24,13), (7,8)]    
x_arr = []
y_arr = []
for x,y in points:
    x_arr.append(x)
    y_arr.append(y)
plt.scatter(x_arr,y_arr)
```

Comment: the amount of correct answers to this questions just shows how confusing this library is in use

Comment: @g_uint Since at least 10 years there is *one* obvious way and that is calling the `invert_yaxis()` method.

Comment: @BlackJack what is obvious to you might not be obvious to another :)

Answer (score 816, accepted):

There is a new API that makes this even simpler.

```
plt.gca().invert_xaxis()
```

and/or

```
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
```

Comment: Be aware that you have to set the axis limits *before* you invert the axis, otherwise it will un-invert it again.

Comment: Would sure be nice if it took a Boolean argument.  When called repeatedly, you're just flipping it back and forth.

Comment: @Tim Whitcomb's answer below works for specific axis objects. Is there a way to apply `invert_yaxis()` to a particular axis? (Distinction can be important when using sublots.)

Answer (score 92):

[DisplacedAussie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051744/pyplot-reverse-y-axis/2052203#2052203)'s answer is correct, but usually a shorter method is just to reverse the single axis in question:

```
plt.scatter(x_arr, y_arr)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim()[::-1])
```

where the `gca()` function returns the current Axes instance and the `[::-1]` reverses the list.

Answer (score 59):

You could also use function exposed by the axes object of the scatter  plot

```
scatter = plt.scatter(x, y)
ax = scatter.axes
ax.invert_xaxis()
ax.invert_yaxis()
```

Comment: I was wondering why my 3D wireframe was not giving me the same date as the map. Invert the x axis.

Answer (score 24):

Use [matplotlib.pyplot.axis()](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axis)

`axis([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])`

So you could add something like this at the end:

```
plt.axis([min(x_arr), max(x_arr), max(y_arr), 0])
```

Although you might want padding at each end so that the extreme points don't sit on the border.

Comment: This has an advantage over the first two answers that it fixes the orientation, not flip it every time (which is an issue if you need to call it in a loop).

Answer (score 23):

If you're in ipython in `pylab` mode, then

```
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
show()
```

the `show()` is required to make it update the current figure.

Answer (score 15):

Another similar method to those described above is to use `plt.ylim` for example:

```
plt.ylim(max(y_array), min(y_array))
```

This method works for me when I'm attempting to compound multiple datasets on Y1 and/or Y2

Comment: This is the simplest method and should be on the top.
Here is an x-axis version for anyone looking to directly copy -
plt.xlim(max(x_axis_array), min(x_axis_array))

Answer (score 8):

using ylim() might be the best approach for your purpose:

```
xValues = list(range(10))
quads = [x** 2 for x in xValues]
plt.ylim(max(quads), 0)
plt.plot(xValues, quads)
```

will result:[image]

Comment: How is this different to @Mortsde's answer?

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can use the [matplotlib.pyplot.axis()](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axis) function, which allows you inverting any of the plot axis

```
ax = matplotlib.pyplot.axis()
matplotlib.pyplot.axis((ax[0],ax[1],ax[3],ax[2]))
```

Or if you prefer to only reverse the X-axis, then

```
matplotlib.pyplot.axis((ax[1],ax[0],ax[2],ax[3]))
```

Indeed, you can invert both axis:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.axis((ax[1],ax[0],ax[3],ax[2]))
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are doing this in a subplot, here is the solution i found

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, sharex = True)
for i in range(2):
    ax[i].plot(xdata, ydata)
axs = plt.gca()
axs.invert_xaxis()
```

While using sharex, last two lines needs to be outside the for loop

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If using matplotlib you can try:

`matplotlib.pyplot.xlim(l, r)
matplotlib.pyplot.ylim(b, t)`

These two lines set the limits of the x and y axes respectively. For the x axis, the first argument l sets the left most value, and the second argument r sets the right most value. For the y axis, the first argument b sets the bottom most value, and the second argument t sets the top most value.