# Reverse y-axis and Draw w.r.t it in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8280500/2106753) has beautifully showed how to reverse the y-axis. However, I now wish to draw all my dots, etc. **with respect to this reversed version of coordinate system**.

I find the following all fail this purpose:

```
plt.figure()
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.plot([1,2],[1,3]) # just a random line


plt.figure()
plt.plot([1,2],[1,3]) # just a random line
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
```

How may I fix it and let it work?

---

For me, if I use an OOP-style figure, i.e.

```
fig = plt.figure()
axes = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])
axes.plot([1,2],[1,3]) # just a random line
axes.invert_yaxis()
```

it works.

But for the current two non-OOP styles listed above, a new figure with a reversed y-axis is created, but the line is not there.

Comment: Both of those work correctly for me. What happens if you try `fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1); ax1.invert_yaxis(); ax1.plot([1,2],[1,3])` and `fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots(1,1); ax2.plot([1,2],[1,3]); ax2.invert_yaxis()`

Comment: @ali_m  Please see the updates. :)

Comment: You need to call `plt.draw()` after the `axes.plot`.  You never trigger a re-draw in the OO-style code.

Answer (score 1):

I still can't reproduce your original error using the snippet you posted (is that really all of your code?), but what you're describing sounds like it could be caused by a race condition when you call `plt.gca()` twice in quick succession.  You could perhaps try inserting a short pause between plotting your two figures:

```
import time

plt.figure()
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.plot([1,2],[1,3]) # just a random line

time.sleep(0.1)

plt.figure()
plt.plot([1,2],[1,3]) # just a random line
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
```

However, as a more general point I would strongly recommend that you avoid using `gca()` and `gcf()` except for convenience during interactive sessions - it's much more Pythonic to pass the axes or figure objects explicitly, and it makes it way easier to keep track of exactly which axes/figures are being modified.