# How to reverse the y-axis of the imported image in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

**For duplicate-markers:** I am fully aware that there are some similar questions in `matplotlib`, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8280500/2881553). My question is **about `Tkinter` not `matplotlib`**.

I am now importing Lena into python and drawing a green dot at her hat with

```
In [72]: from PIL import Image
   ....: import matplotlib.pylab as plt
   ....: im = Image.open('lena.jpg')
   ....: fig = plt.figure()
   ....: axes = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])
   ....: axes.imshow(im)
   ....: axes.scatter(50, 50, marker='s', color='green')
Out[72]: <matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0xb3e2ef0>
```

*(Please ignore the red dot)*

[image]

I now want the green dot `(50, 50)` to be still on Lena's hat, but I also want the green dot to be drawn at the left bottom corner instead of the left top corner.

I expect something like this:

[image]

As seen, I managed to do this easily in `matplotlib` with one additional line:

```
axes.invert_yaxis()
```

## Question

I am now drawing on the canvas in `Tkinter`. 
How may I achieve the same effect?

---

**Update**

Lena is merely for illustration of my purpose. In my real problem, I am not importing anything in `Tkinter`. I **merely draw on a empty canvas**. I am **reluctant to modify my data, I only wish to have the drawing upside down.** Like in my Lena illustration, the coordinate is still `(50, 50)`. The difference is that now it is in the left bottom instead of top corner.

Comment: Could you show your Tkinter code?

Comment: @falsetru My code is quite a mess. But I think I've made it clear, though I only use the description. You can think my code as one drawing dots on the canvas, which is extremely simple. Now I wish my left bottom corner to be (0, 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that this would be simple with code like the below:

```
import Tkinter
#Set up a basic canvas
top = Tkinter.Tk()
canv = Tkinter.Canvas(top, bg="brown", height=250, width=300)

#Replace with what ever values you want
x = 50
y = 50

#Draw the first dot
line1 = canv.create_line(x, y, x - 2, y - 2, fill="green", width=3)
#This next line is pretty much all it takes to find the Y inverse
y = canv.winfo_reqheight() - y
#Draw the second dot
line2 = canv.create_line(x, y, x - 2, y - 2, fill="green", width = 3)

canv.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

This returns the following:

[image: Flipped Y axis]

Basically all I did was get the canvas height (250), and subtract the previous Y value (50) from it, which returned the Y inverse (200). Not exactly a built in function, but the actual flipping part was very simple. Hope that was what you were looking for... Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

An angle can be used like such:

```
image = Image.open("lena.jpg")
angle = 180
tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image.rotate(angle))
...
```

It would be possible to draw the picture, and use reversed coordinates (so when you know the size of the canvas, instead of saying `50x50`, you could use `(max-50)x(max-50)`.

The question is whether `axes.imshow` can handle the `ImageTk.PhotoImage`. Then again, I am not entirely sure if you'd just want this on a Tkinter canvas instead, e.g.:

```
canvas_obj = self.canvas.create_image(250, 250, image=tkimage)
```

Comment: Oh, Lena is merely for illustration of my purpose. In my real problem, I am not importing anything in Tkinter. I merely draw on a empty canvas. I am reluctant to modify my data, I only wish to have the drawing upside down.

Comment: @mavErick So the question is to reverse the canvas? Or would drawing inversely be okay as well (then you draw everything using `(max-50)` for the inverse of 50)?

Comment: I think drawing reversely will do, but as I said I am really reluctant to modify my data points specially for drawing.

Comment: What do you draw? What is the purpose? could you save the points first to a file which you would then reload and reverse? I don't think it is possible to rotate the canvas in the way you describe.

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be asking for is a 2D World to Viewport Transformation:

Take an area defined in "world coordinates" (say 10 metres by 10 metres)
and map it to an area defined in canvas coordinates.

eg.

```
from tkinter import *

xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax = 0,0,10,10   # world
umin,vmin,umax,vmax = 0,480,640,0 # viewport (note: y reversed)

points = [(2,2), (4,4), (7,7), (8,8)]  # some "world" points

def world_to_viewport(worldpoint):
    x,y = worldpoint
    u = (x - xmin)*((umax - umin)/(xmax - xmin)) + umin
    v = (y - ymin)*((vmax - vmin)/(ymax - ymin)) + vmin
    return u,v

def pixel_to_world(pixel):
    u,v = pixel
    x = (u - umin)*((xmax - xmin)/(umax - umin)) + xmin
    y = (v - vmin)*((ymax - ymin)/(vmax - vmin)) + ymin
    return x,y

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=640, height=480, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()

def on_click(event):
    root.title('%s,%s' %(pixel_to_world((event.x,event.y))))

canvas.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', on_click)

r = 5
for point in points:
    cx,cy = world_to_viewport(point)
    canvas.create_oval(cx-r,cy-r,cx+r,cy+r,fill='red')

root.mainloop()
```