# Tkinter coordinate system

Tags: python, tkinter, coordinate-systems, tkinter-canvas

I have been amusing (and instructing) myself reprogramming one of my turtle games into tkinter.
Only trouble is, unlike turtle,  the y coordinates run from the top to the bottom and I can't find any way of changing this. 
I am very reluctant to undertake a major effort changing the values and signs in the very many x,y coordinate calculations in the program.
Consequently my lovely landscape is presented upside down!

Comment: Hi @nick, Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584629/how-to-reverse-the-y-axis-of-the-imported-image-in-tkinter)? Does it help/solve?

Comment: thanks !  didn't realise it was already answered, I'll give it  a go     appreciate the help!