# NetworkX : Flip graph

Tags: python, graph, networkx, flip

Is there a way to make graph generation in the opposite order i.e. I want to generate the graph vertically flipped.

or if I can flip it with some matplotlib subroutine before it is drawn !!

F.e.:
I want 357 and 358 to be on top, and 1-6 to be at the bottom

[image]

Comment: Please provide a sample input and output.  It's not clear to me what you are asking to do.  (I think you are using the word 'generate' differently from what I would mean).

Comment: You can change the order of either axis easily: see [Reverse Y-Axis in PyPlot](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8280500) (@Joel's answer keeps the positioning under your control, which may be advantageous in other ways)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just interchange the coordinates of your positions.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = fast_gnp_random_graph(20,0.1)
pos = nx.sprint_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos)
flipped_pos = {node: (x,-y) for (node, (x,y)) in pos.items())
plt.clf()
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos = flipped_pos)
```