# Order of bars in prettyplotlib barchart

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, prettyplotlib

**How to control the order of the bars in `prettyplotlib` barchart?**

From `prettyplotlib==0.1.7`

Using the standard `ppl.bar` I could get a barchart as such:

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import prettyplotlib as ppl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

counter = {1:1, 2:4, 3:9, 4:16, 5:25, 6:36, 7:49}

x, y = zip(*counter.items())

ppl.bar(ax, x , y, annotate=True, grid='y')
```

[image]

But if I want to reverse the x-axis bars,when I change the `x` list, the order of bars reversed but not the labels:

```
ppl.bar(ax, list(reversed(x)) , y, annotate=True, grid='y')
```

[image]

I could use the `xticklabels` argument:

```
ppl.bar(ax, list(reversed(x)) , y, annotate=True, xticklabels=list('7654321'), grid='y')
```

But that didn't work too, it returns the same right bar order, wrong x-axis labels:

[image]

Strangely, when I reverse the list of the `xticklabels`,

```
 ppl.bar(ax, list(reversed(x)) , y, annotate=True, xticklabels=list('1234567'), grid='y')
```

I've got what I needed but it's strange now that the `x` list is reversed but the `xticklabels` are not...

[image]

But if I removed the reversed on the `x` list:

```
ppl.bar(ax, x , y, annotate=True, xticklabels=list('1234567'), grid='y')
```

we get the first same graph as `ppl.bar(ax, x , y, annotate=True, grid='y')`...

[image]

Comment: Why not reverse the axis properly? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051744/reverse-y-axis-in-pyplot Also prettyplotlib seems to have been abandoned for years and the dev suggests using seaborn instead.

Comment: Ah... Yes, seaborn is much better maintained.

Comment: Note that while seaborn adds a lot of style functionality to matplotlib its main purpose is to easily interface with pandas. All seaborn styles are readily available from within matplotlib and unless you know what you are doing, I would recommend creating usual plots with matplotlib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since prettyplotlib is mostly responsible for the style, your problem is actually not specific to its use, and you need to use native matplotlib methods to reverse your x axis:

```
import numpy as np
import prettyplotlib as ppl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

counter = {1:1, 2:4, 3:9, 4:16, 5:25, 6:36, 7:49}

x, y = zip(*counter.items())

ppl.bar(ax, x , y, annotate=True, grid='y')
ax.invert_xaxis() # <-- fix
```

The result is exactly what you need: both plot and labels are reversed:

[image: pretty result]

This is also the semantically correct approach to your problem: your data is still the same, you only want it to be represented differently.

Comment: Thanks @AndrasDeak! I went ahead an use `seaborn` though =)

Comment: @alvas I agree that's the right course of action:) But since you didn't delete your question for a while I figured I should add an answer that answers your prettyplotlib question ;)