# Mayavi: How can I flip the Z-axis of a scene?

Tags: python, 3d, axis, volume, mayavi

I am trying to flip Z-axis in the mayavi volumetric 3D plot. I figured how to rotate the camera etc, but that is not what I want. I just want to flip the direction of Z-axis. Without manipulating the data itself

```
#Minimum working example

import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab

x, y, z = np.ogrid[-5:5:64j, -5:5:64j, -5:5:64j] #Generate XYZ
data = np.arange(x.shape[0])
x = x.ravel()
y = y.ravel()
z = z.ravel()
mlab.points3d(x, y, z, data) #Produce volumetric plot
mlab.axes(xlabel='X', ylabel='Y', zlabel='Z') #Display axis
mlab.orientation_axes()
mlab.show()
```

Comment: Just have a look at this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051744/reverse-y-axis-in-pyplot

Comment: @Bazingaa but this staff is about matplotlib. We are talking about Mayavi here

Comment: Ok, I thought similar features exist also for mayavi as well.

Comment: @Bazingaa I have tried, but even if they do, it is not that straight forward

Comment: I found `mlab.axes(ranges = [...])` where one can specify the x, y, z axes ranges but it just seem to reverse the axis tick labels. Since you plot is symmetric across [001[ plane, it's hard to see the effect of reversing the z values in this command

Comment: @Bazingaa I checked, indeed it just switches the labels, not the actual plot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please explain what you mean using non-symmetric data using this example.
Do you want negative z to be at the top side?
And why does rotating the camera not produce the result you want to see?

You can add the code from the macro editor (explained below).

```
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab

x, y, z = np.ogrid[-5:5:64j, -5:5:64j, -5:5:64j] #Generate XYZ
data = np.arange(x.shape[0])
x = x.ravel()
y = y.ravel()
z = z.ravel()

# Recorded script from Mayavi2
from numpy import array
try:
    engine = mayavi.engine
except (AttributeError, NameError):
    from mayavi.api import Engine
    engine = Engine()
    engine.start()
if len(engine.scenes) == 0:
    engine.new_scene()
# -------------------------------------------
scene = engine.scenes[0]
scene.scene.camera.position = [20.68813263960946, 20.334388554161922, 20.518300376103046]
scene.scene.camera.focal_point = [0.24373197555541992, 0.24373197555541992, 0.25]
scene.scene.camera.view_angle = 30.0
scene.scene.camera.view_up = [-0.41179533881878827, -0.4046701524210215, 0.81649658092772626]
scene.scene.camera.clipping_range = [15.729834995160559, 58.864284541884331]
scene.scene.camera.compute_view_plane_normal()
scene.scene.render()

mlab.points3d(x, y, z, data) #Produce volumetric plot
mlab.axes(xlabel='X', ylabel='Y', zlabel='Z') #Display axis
mlab.orientation_axes()

mlab.show()
```

If you really can set the view you want manually I would just do that.
To get the correct coordinates to pass to `mlab.view()` read them from the interactive plot while rotating the scene:

[image]

Comment: Agreed, your data example is better for visualization. Yes, indeed I what negative Z on top. I played around with camera settings, but never managed to get how to set camera as I want

Comment: Were you able to manually rotate the image to get the result you want to see? Could you paste an image?

Comment: but are those the same I use in mlab.view? Becasue I see that view can operate azimuth, elevation, distance, etc. While scen has attributes position, view angle, view up etc. Not really clear to me, which one to use

Comment: Yes, I also noticed that. `view_angle` might be `azimuth`, and maybe `view_up` is a unit vector that can be used to calculate `elevation`.

Comment: But you could use the camera settings directly, instead of using ``view`. I will add code in a minute.