# Reverse points in an array - Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have an array of points that I am plotting in Matplotlib. Here is my code:

```
masked = r['masks']

  fig=plt.figure()
  ax2=fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])

  colors = ['b', 'g', 'r', 'c', 'm','y']

  for idx in range(masked.shape[2]):
    array = masked[:,:,idx]

    xs = []
    ys = []
    for i in range(len(array)):
        for j in range(len(array[0])):
            if array[i][j] == True:
                xs.append(j)
                ys.append(i)
    # ys.reverse()

    ax2.scatter(xs, ys, color=str(colors[idx]))
  
  plt.show()
```

And that gives me this plot:
[PLOT 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhWLY.png)

When I then uncomment the `ys.reverse()` in the code snippet above, I expect the image to be vertically flipped, but instead I get this, which is completely wrong:

[PLOT 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AV7r4.png)

How can I fix this and make the plot correctly flipped? NOTE: I do not want a solution such as `plt.gca.invert_yaxis()` - I want the **points** arrays to be corrected.

Thanks,
Vineeth

Comment: If you wanna flip the image horizontally you need to flip the x-axis right?

Comment: Oh sorry - vertical flip! Just edited the question @SimonFredrich

Comment: It’s a scatter plot so reversing y will muck up the data, i.e. you have points (x0, y0) that will become (x0, yn). If you want to _flip_ `y` without just flipping the plot axis you need to do something like `y = y.max() - y`. You can replace `y.max()` with a more appropriate number.

Comment: Thanks @DavidHoffman, make an answer and I'll mark as accepted.

Comment: Matplotlib can flip the axis for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8280500/1011724

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reverse Y-Axis in PyPlot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051744/reverse-y-axis-in-pyplot)

Comment: No @Dan, as I mentioned in the question, I do not want a solution that flips the axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s a scatter plot so reversing `ys` will muck up the data, i.e. you have points `(x0, y0)` that will become `(x0, yn)`.

If you want to flip `ys` without just flipping the plot axis you need to do something like `ys = (ys.max() + ys.min()) - ys`. You can replace `(ys.max() + ys.min())` with a more appropriate number.

In your code you'd replace:

```
ax2.scatter(xs, ys, color=str(colors[idx]))
```

With:

```py
xs = np.asarray(xs)
ys = np.asarray(ys)

# reverse ys
ys = (ys.max() + ys.min()) - ys

ax2.scatter(xs, ys, color=str(colors[idx]))
```

Answer (score -1):

When you do a scatter plot what matplotlib does is take the nth element of the x and y arrays and use those coordinates to draw a point.
This is why just reversing the order doesn't work (at least I haven't found a working solution that way).
What you should do instead is transform the points correctly - warning, some linear algebra ahead!
The idea is simple:

- First subtract the xs mean to every xs point (its mean will then be zero)
- Then, transform the xs and ys points with a horizontal flipping matrix [[-1, 0], [0, 1]]
- Finally, add the xs mean back, so the points are again x-centered where they were before

So after creating the arrays you should try the following:

```
xs_mean = sum(xs) / len(xs)
matrix = [[-1, 0], [0, 1]]

xss, yss = [], []
for x, y in zip(xss, yss):
    [x, y] = np.matmul(matrix, [x, y])
    xss.append(x + x_mean)
    yss.append(y)

ax2.scatter(xss, yss, color=str(colors[idx]))
```

I am sure there is might be a simpler way to do this, but I hope this proves useful

Comment: I tried that @gilbertocunha, it still gives me the PLOT 2 image as shown above. Not sure what's wrong. And just edited the question - it should be a vertical flip.

Comment: sorry, i just now realized it, I am going to edit the comment

Comment: @VineethVejus there you go, this should work now! If anything wasn't clear, just say so