# Change tick direction

Tags: matplotlib

How can I make the tick markers point outwards in matplotlib?

[image: Coordinates marker of x and y are pointing inside the graph not outside the graph]

Comment: The axis restrictions can be [reversed](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/invert_axes.html) or handled by the [API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051744/reverse-y-axis-in-pyplot).

Comment: What do you mean by invert?  Swap x for y?  Get in screen space?

Comment: @JodyKlymak I mean how to control the small grid lines on x and y axis. In the image its on the inner side of the axes, but,  I want it to be in the outward direction

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your title to use the Matplotlib terminology.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment more than your initial question, I think what you want to do is:

```
ax.tick_params(axis="both",direction="out")
```

Have a look [at matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks. It is exactly what i wanted to do