# Reverse Y-axis in dumbbell plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

So i created a dumbbell plot, but the Y-axis is not in alphabetical order. How can i reverse this?
Thank you.enter imag[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THlrZ.png)e description here

Comment: See this:[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051744/reverse-y-axis-in-pyplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051744/reverse-y-axis-in-pyplot)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.