# How to flip the axis of a plot under ruby?

Tags: ruby, daru

I wrote a ruby function to display the contents of a Daru dataframe `df`:

```
def plot_dataframe(df)
    test = df.plot type: :line, x: :value, y: :depth
    test.export_html(filename='test')
return
end
```

This outputs an html file named `test.html`.

How can I flip the y axis (ordinate) so that the depth starts at 0 and increases downwards?

I am looking for an equivalent to Python's [invert_yaxis()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8280500/6440589).

---

At @Serge de Gosson de Varennes' request, here is a MRE:

```
require 'json'
require 'daru'
require 'nyaplot'


df = Daru::DataFrame.new(
value: [1.2, 1.4, 1.1, 1.0, 1.0],
depth: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] 
)

 

test = df.plot type: :line, x: :value, y: :depth, y_reverse: true
test.export_html(filename='MRE')
```

This outputs:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one of two ways:

```
def plot_dataframe(df)
    test = df.plot type: :line, x: :value, y: :depth, y_reverse: true
    test.export_html(filename='test')
return
end
```

or

```
def plot_dataframe(df)
    test = df.plot type: :line, x: :value, y: :depth, y_axis_scale: :reverse
    test.export_html(filename='test')
return
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Serge. Now this seemed like an easy enough fix but alas it did not succeed in inverting my y-axis. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Without any of the input data it is hard to know what might be wrong. Share a minimal reproducible example of the data.

Comment: Bonne idée! I added a MRE to my original question.