# Is it possible to change the position of the circles in the matplotlib-venn/venn3 diagram?

Tags: python, matplotlib-venn

I would like for the circles to be placed like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue. Figured out the following works pretty well:

```
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
```

Found this out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051744/how-to-invert-the-x-or-y-axis)