Transfer numpy array coordinates to matplotlib coordinates
I do not know whether I'm doing a thinking mistake but I struggle a bit with the transfer from numpy array coordinates to matplotlib coordinates. As an example I underpin piece of sources of the implementation of MiniSom.
You will find an array definition as follows
activation_map = zeros((x, y))

That's a normal 2D array with x rows and y columns.
To get the coordinates of a best matching unit regarding a dataset the important part is:
def winner(x):
  ...
  unravel_index(activation_map.argmin(), activation_map.shape)

That's also pretty well: argmin() without axis specification returns the index into the flattened array and unravel_index() translates this index into coordinates of a given shape. At the end I have coordinates of a numpy array. Pretty understandable!
But now the transfer to matplotlib isn't clear - at least for me. I use a fragment of the example BasicUsage. The plotted grid corresponds to the shape of activation_map.
for cnt, xx in enumerate(data):
  w = winner(xx)
  plt.plot(w[0]+.5, w[1]+.5, 'a specific marker symbol', ...)

A marker is placed onto the matplotlib grid. For e.g. when w results in [3,5] the marker is placed at position x=3.5 and y=5.5 (+.5 is only for placing the marker in the center). The position [0,0] of the grid is in the lower left corner. From this point of view, the placement of the marker is understandable. But the position [0,0] of the array is in the upper left corner. I would expect that the coordinate [0,0] I get from winner() should be used to place a marker in the upper left corner and not in the lower left corner.
Edit 1: The example can be found here:
https://github.com/JustGlowing/minisom/blob/master/examples/BasicUsage.ipynb
Edit 2: A short running example according to the example in Edit 1:
activation_map = np.array([[1, 2, 0], [2, 3, 2]])

w = np.unravel_index(activation_map.argmin(), activation_map.shape)
print(w)

plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 3, 1))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 2, 1))
x = np.array([0, w[0], 2])
y = np.array([0, w[1], 1])
plt.plot(x, y, 'x', markersize=12, markeredgewidth=2)
plt.show()

The short example demonstrates my problem. The markers [0,0] and [2,1] are only set to show the entire grid. The marker for w is set on the coordinate-system where it's expected from an math point of view, but not from a numpy array point of view.
Any helps for clarifications I'm greatful!
All the best

Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] so that readers can run your code to answer your question.

Done! I've included a link to a short running example

Thanks, but a [mre] is about providing code that users can run (on its own) to reproduce your issue. While the provided link is helpful for understanding the expected outcome, it doesn't show the problem itself. So, the request is for the smallest version of your code that can exemplify the issue.

Thanks! I've included a short running example.

Do you just want to flip the direction of the y-axis? https://stackoverflow.com/q/2051744/3501128

I think that's it! All other axes can be as are with exception the first axis (y on the matplotlib grid).

If it is just the orientation that irritates you, you can simply flip the y-axis orientation. Based on your provided minimum example:
def test_example():
    activation_map = np.array([[1, 2, 0], [2, 3, 2]])

    w = np.unravel_index(activation_map.argmin(), activation_map.shape)
    print(w)

    plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 3, 1))
    plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 2, 1))
    x = np.array([0, w[0], 2])
    y = np.array([0, w[1], 1])
    plt.plot(x, y, 'x', markersize=12, markeredgewidth=2)
    plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
    plt.show()

